# "How to fix "Display Returned Value From One Def To Another" "

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a program to take sentences from a text file and match the name of cities from a JSON file. Matching Isn't working and I am not able to pass my return value.

I have Tried First doing Simply without creating a class and Checked with the static city.

```
import json

with open("store.txt", "r+") as g, open("city.json") as c:
   dat1 = json.load(c)
   dat = g.readlines()
   # print(dat)


# def hel():
#     for items1 in dat1:
#         gat = items1.get("name")
#         print(gat)

class One:

    def __init__(self):
       self.dat = dat
       self.dat1 = dat1

    def leh(self):
       for items in self.dat:
          # print(items)
          # for hy in items:
          return items

    def main(self):
       returned = test_obj.leh()
       print(returned)
       # for items1 in self.dat1:
       #     gat = items1.get("name")
       #     if gat in returned:
       #         print("Got it")


if __name__ == '__main__':
   test_obj = One()
   test_obj.main()
```

I expect the passed value to print and match cities name with the sentences stored in the text file.

Lines in store.txt:

" Delhi is a nice city."
   "London is nice."

Lines in city.json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Surat",
    "country": "IN"
  },
  {
    "id": 1259229,
    "name": "London",
    "country": "GB"
  },
  {
    "id": 1273294,
    "name": "Delhi",
    "country": "IN"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post a few lines from each file to make your question easier to understand

Comment: your `leh` function is not parsing the entire file. It is returning after reading the first line.

Comment: I need to parse entire file data.

Comment: Still, it's not clear what you're asking.. What is the passed value you are referring to? Are you trying to print the sentences from `store.txt` or values from the json file?

Comment: I am trying to take all "name" from JSON and search them in the sentences stored in the text file. If it matches Then some operation is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand how json works. Since we're reading a file, which is read as a string, we
should use `json.loads` which accepts strings. Another problem is that `json.loads` expects a whole string in json,
but since our json file is split into lines, we need to find a way to put it all together in one string.
One option would be `file.read().strip()` which reads the whole file and then removes line separators like `\n`.
Another option would be `"".join(file.readlines())` which splits the files into lines and then connects them in a
string. Then after we parse the json, we just need to read the text file in lines and iterate through both them and the
values in json. Just in case a city in the text file is written like `LoNdOn` I am using `.lower()` which converts it
to `london`.

```
import json


with open("city.json") as json_file:
    parsed = json.loads(json_file.read().strip())

with open("store.txt") as text_file:
    sentences = text_file.readlines()

for element in parsed:
    for sentence in sentences:
        if element['name'].lower() in sentence.lower():
            print("{} was found!".format(element))
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. Solved it by using Different method. But your code is much better than mine so i am gonna use this. and I want this code in while loop. So when it done cheking then it should again go for reading the text files. Incase changes are done in File.

Comment: I am glad I helped :)

Comment: Can you help with looping and reading continuously file for text. Getting an error at my side.

Comment: it's really nothing more than a `while True:` above reading the text file. I'd suggest you study python before writing anything.